# Prove that : $MB=MA+MC$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

Problem :

Let $ABC$ be a equilateral triangle

$C$ : circumscribed circle of $ABC$

$M$ point in arc $AB$ , $M≠B$

$D$ point in $[BM]$ such : $AD=AM$

> Prove that :

$MB=MA+MC$

Can you give me some hints or idea to approach it ?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by $D$ point in $[BM]$? Your picture doesn't show that...

Comment: Why do we invent the point $D$ when we have to show something that in not involving $D$? And of course, in the given situation $MB<AB=AC<MC<MA+MC$, so please correct at all places. Inserting a misleading picture is worse than inserting no picture. (And inserting no picture would make us ask for one, and for the own thoughts / attempts to solve the issue.) Please review and build sentences, so that digesting the geometric situation is done with easy.